# stream video with eventmachine?

Tags: ruby, video-streaming, eventmachine

It seems to me that [EM::FileStreamer](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/FileStreamer.html) should be usable out of the box, but I tried it with the `<video>` tag and with an embedded Quicktime plugin, but neither one would actually show the video.

I've connected to my EM server with telnet and found that it does indeed stream my video file.  I'm at a loss as to why it's not buffering and playing in my browser. Anyone have any hints for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work, however the video must be encoded properly to stream in that fashion. I am assuming your using an mp4? If so, have you run qt-faststart on the file?

Here's an article with a bit of info.

http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/11/12/how-to-make-mp4-progressive-with-qt-faststart/

I also have my sample video encoding app on github, which does this automatically for you when you upload videos.

https://github.com/zquestz/asset-manager

Just make sure qt-faststart is in your PATH. Once the index information is at the beginning of the file, thing should work as expected.

Videos encoded with libtheora should work out of the box for supported browsers.

Comment: Awesome! That sounds really encouraging. You're right - my video _is_ encoded as mp4. I'll try out your steps tonight and then accept your answer. Thanks!